# How to convert NLA Tracks to proper Actions?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

I created 16 animations for my model using actions but some of my animations looks like this. How can I get rid of this NLA thing and make all animations as actions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are already actions. If you look closely, you will see that they have the same icon as any normal action.

[image: 1]

If you open the *Nonlinear Animation* editor, you will see that they are just inside an *Action Strip* (2) in an *NLA Track* (1).

[image: 2]

If you want to view the action, you can either isolate the NLA track that contains its strip by pressing the star icon of the NLA track (next screenshot), or select the strip and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to edit the strip's action in isolation (last screenshot).

[image: 3]

Note how the other NLA tracks become transparent.

[image: 4]

Note how the active strip becomes green. Also, the keyframes of its action show up in the *Timeline* and other editors.

---

If you want to delete the strips, in the *Nonlinear Animation* editor, select all tracks, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Just make sure the actions have a user (or a fake user), or they will be discarded when you close the file.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!